# Highcharts - updating series leads to tooltip-related error (mouseOver)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As can be seen [in this simple fiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/43ygghz3/1/) triggering the mouseOver event on a data point and updating the series' properties via `series.update()` leads to a js error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tooltipOptions' of null
```

The code:

```
plotOptions: {
         series: {
             cursor: 'pointer',
             point: {
                 events: {
                     mouseOver: function () {
                         console.log('why does an error appear?');
                         this.series.update({
                             lineWidth: 10
                         });
                     },
                     mouseOut: function () {
                         console.log('bla');
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     },
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks for info.

When setting the tooltip to `enabled: false`, the error message is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function highcharts.js:300
  r.onMouseOver                              highcharts.js:300
  Wa.runPointActions                         highcharts.js:158
  Wa.onContainerMouseMove                    highcharts.js:165
  b.onmousemove                              highcharts.js:167
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you use mouseOver event, then you catch this event many times, so series update is also called many times. You should consider another event like click, which will be called one time.

Comment: thanks for your answer; so I did nothing "wrong" here, but the plugin did? Astonishingly, mouseOut also produces errors, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJz9BRJRe9am6sCf2/43ygghz3/3/  --- mouse events on points are not possible at all?

Comment: when `click` on a point, the plugin fires `mouseOut`. This is strange.

Comment: mouseOut is not needed when you use click, remove it and leave only click.

Comment: okay ;) it really seems mouseOver and mouseOut are buggy. when fired even once, they generate errors.... :( gonna submit a report on that. thanx anyway! :)

Comment: Not a solution yet, but what I can definetely tell is that it has to do with the `series.update()` function. This function sets all properties of object `this` to `null`. As it says in the doc: `For a clean and precise handling of new options, all methods and elements from the series is removed, and it is initiated from scratch.` 

Obviously, this interferes with the other events that are called in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `enableMouseTracking` option as `false` first to get rid of the error:

```
chart.options.plotOptions.pie.enableMouseTracking = false;
```